# Two overloaded methods, same actions, causing duplicate code

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have two methods that take either a `Circle` or a `Scene` and make the background flash red - green - blue by changing the `fill` value every N ms.

The two methods:

```
private void makeRGB(Circle c) {
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(c.getFill() == Color.RED) {
                c.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (c.getFill() == Color.GREEN) {
                c.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            } else {
                c.setFill(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    },0, RGB_CHANGE_PERIOD);
}

private void makeRGB(Scene s) {
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(s.getFill() == Color.RED) {
                s.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (s.getFill() == Color.GREEN) {
                s.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            } else {
                s.setFill(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    },0, RGB_CHANGE_PERIOD);
}
```

Obviously these are very similar, however as `Circle` and `Scene` aren't in the same inheritance tree I can't use the approach of calling a superclass of them both containing the `.setFill()` / `.getFill()` methods.

How would I go about removing code duplication here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, you remove duplicate code by factoring the common code into a function/method/class and parameterizing the parts that vary. In this case, what varies is the way you retrieve the current fill, and the way you set the new fill. The [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package provides the appropriate types for parametrizing these, so you can do:

```
private void makeRGB(Circle c) {
    makeRGB(c::getFill, c:setFill);
}

private void makeRGB(Scene s) {
    makeRGB(s::getFill, s:setFill);
}

private void makeRGB(Supplier<Paint> currentFill, Consumer<Paint> updater) {
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(currentFill.get() == Color.RED) {
                updater.accept(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (currentFill.get() == Color.GREEN) {
                updater.accept(Color.BLUE);
            } else {
                updater.accept(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    },0, RGB_CHANGE_PERIOD);
}
```

Note, though, that you should not change the UI from a background thread. You should really do

```
private void makeRGB(Supplier<Paint> currentFill, Consumer<Paint> updater) {
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                if(currentFill.get() == Color.RED) {
                    updater.accept(Color.GREEN);
                } else if (currentFill.get() == Color.GREEN) {
                    updater.accept(Color.BLUE);
                } else {
                    updater.accept(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
    },0, RGB_CHANGE_PERIOD);
}
```

or, (better), [use a `Timeline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task) to do things on a periodic basis.

As noted in the comments, you can also provide a `Map` that maps each color to the color that comes after it. Combining all this gives:

```
private final Map<Paint, Paint> fills = new HashMap<>();

// ...

    fills.put(Color.RED, Color.GREEN);
    fills.put(Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE);
    fills.put(Color.BLUE, Color.RED);

// ...

private void makeRGB(Circle c) {
    makeRGB(c::getFill, c:setFill);
}

private void makeRGB(Scene s) {
    makeRGB(s::getFill, s:setFill);
}

private void makeRGB(Supplier<Paint> currentFill, Consumer<Paint> updater) {

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(Duration.millis(RGB_CHANGE_PERIOD), 
        e-> updater.accept(fills.get(currentFill.get())));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}
```

Comment: Also, a `static Map<Color, Coolor> nextColorMap` could replace the multi-storied `if` statement with a single `updater.accept(nextColorMap.get(currentFill.get()));`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what I was looking for; although I need to look into the `Consumer` class more :) @9000 Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Instead of passing `Consumer`/`Supplier` you could simply pass the property, since it allows you to set and get the value...

Comment: @fabian True indeed. (This technique does work in more general cases, though.)